# How to filter everything that comes back from Entity Framework by a property on my entities base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The class which all my entities inherit from looks like this:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

what I'm trying to accomplish is for EF to automatically filter out any Status which is "Deleted" any time I bring back results from the database. With the searching I've done I've found the common way to do this is by override OnModelCreating In the Db context class like so:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityBase>().Map(m => m.Requires("Status").HasValue("Active"));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

This is problematic for a couple reasons. First and foremost it doesn't work. As soon as I touch the database I get the error:

> EntityType 'EntityBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   EntityBases: EntityType: EntitySet 'EntityBases' is based on type 'EntityBase' that has no keys defined.

Which is accurate, my base entity does not have a key. However, it's also not an actual table in my DB so it's not supposed to.

My other problem is that this is not actually the filter I want. This uses `.HasValue("Active")` when I'm looking for more of a `.DoesntHaveValue("Deleted")`.

Comment: I am not home so no visual studio so I cannot post a good answer. But what you need to do is to intercept all calls and add the filter to it. Please see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: The `Map` + `Requires` + `HasValue` is not for filtering at all (it's for configuring TPH discriminator). Anyway, what are you asking is not supported out of the box in EF6 (it has been added in EF Core). You could give a try to [Query Filter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-filter) feature of [Entity Framework Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus) package.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up going with the Query Filter suggestion from @ivan-stoev and attached it to the Context constructor. Heres the code for posterity.

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;
```

...

```
public MyContext() : base("MyContext")
{
    this.Filter<EntityBase>(q => q.Where(x => x.Status != "Deleted"));
}
```